# Big Query writing Japanese(utf-8) using to_gbq

Tags: python, selenium, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have tried out to get the data from web site using selenium on GCP, and that is fine to obtain data and show that on the screen by print() command. However when tried out to sending the data to big query using by to_gbq, following error appears and out come is blank data.
Error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 14-30: 
Body ('尚道館・西郷派大東流合気武術総本部') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.
```

The website is a Japanese Page. To solve this I used str.encode(utf-8) command, it seems like that string is propery converted to utf-8 by looking from print(). However it getting same error.
My environment is Python3 on GCP.

```
 data_rows = []
    for e in elems: 
        data = e.text
        data_row = data.splitlines()
        data_row.append(datetime.datetime.now())
        if len(data_row) == 6:
            data_row[0] = data_row[0].encode('utf-8')
            data_row[1] = data_row[1].encode('utf-8')
            data_row[2] = data_row[2].encode('utf-8')
            data_row[3] = data_row[3].encode('utf-8')
            data_row[4] = data_row[4].encode('utf-8')
            data_rows.append(data_row)
    driver.quit()
    sample_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_rows,columns= 
    ['shop_name','category','nearest_station','telephone_number','address','DL_time'])
    print(sample_dataframe)

    sample_dataframe.to_gbq('NTT.aikidou2025', 'robotic-column-270803',if_exists = 'replace')`
```

Comment: Can you try: sample_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(encoding='utf-8')?

Comment: Thank you for your response, when I add the argument following error has occoures.
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-5-972038454e8e> in <module>()
     48                 data_rows.append(data_row)
     49 driver.quit()
---> 50 sample_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data_rows,encoding='utf-8',columns=['shop_name','category','nearest_station','telephone_number','address','DL_time'])
     51 print(sample_dataframe)
     52 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: What version of `panada-gbq` are you using? Looks like this was fixed in `0.3.1`: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/pull/108

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I checked version using pip list. that shown version 0.3.0 so update that the problem is solved. it seems like pip install --upgrade is effective. I had another error but I would like to ask another sled for it seems like another problem.

Comment: @DustinIngram, could you post it as an answer so that community can see it in case some user faces same issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What version of `panads-gbq` are you using? Looks like this was fixed in `0.3.1`: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/pull/108

You can upgrade with `pip install -U pandas-gbq`.

Answer (score 0):

For this ploblem pip install --upgrade was effective